# In RX how to create buffers no faster than they can be processed

Tags: c#, async-await, system.reactive

Using RX's [buffer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) operator allows the creation of batches after a certain number of results have appeared, or after a specified time, whichever is sooner. This is very useful when piping results to, say, a database on another machine, where one wants to keep latency down, but avoid sending huge numbers of requests (one per result).

I have an additional requirement, which is to preserve the ordering of results into the database (some are updates, which must come after the corresponding adds). This means that outgoing requests cannot overlap in case they get out of order.

Ideally each buffer should continue filling up even after it would normally emit if a previous database request has not yet returned, as this will minimise latency and the number of requests going to the database.

How could the following code be modified to make this work?

```
source
  .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 25)
  .Subscribe(async batch => await SendToDatabase(batch));
```

Comment: There is no `Subscribe` overload that accepts asynchronous lambdas. The observables are notifying their subscribers (observers) synchronously by design. The asynchronous lambda in your example is [`async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void), a peculiarity that exists out of the need to make asynchronous event handlers possible (handlers of traditional events), and generally shouldn't be used for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

To force outgoing requests to wait until the previous one has returned before being processed, there is an RX trick which turns each result into an observable which completes only when it has finished processing. By combining these with [concat](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html) the next will not be started until the previous one completes.

```
source
  .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 25)
  .Select(batch => 
    Observable.FromAsync(async () => 
      await SendToDatabase(batch)
    )
  )
  .Concat()
  .Subscribe(async batch => await SendToDatabase(batch));
```

This will still produce batches while waiting, though, so is not a perfect solution.

Comment: This answer is almost correct. But I assume that invoking the `SendToDatabase` twice per element is a mistake. If you don't have to do anything more with an element after saving it, you could just subscribe with an empty `onNext` handler: `.Subscribe(_ => { }, _ => { });`

Answer (score 0):

I have written a new observable extension `BufferAndAct` which does this.

In summary, it takes a time interval, a number (of items), and an action to be applied to each batch. It tries to act on a batch when the time interval expires or when the number of items has been reached, but it will never start acting on a new batch until the previous one has completed, so there is no limit on the potential size of a batch. Modifications could be made to bring this in line with some of the other overloads of `Buffer`.

It uses a further extension `Split` which acts like one of the overloads of `Buffer`, turning an observable of source items into an observable of observables of source items, splitting them when a signal is received from an input observable.

`BufferAndAct` uses `Split` to create an observable which gives a tick when a normal, timed, buffer would be emitted on the source observable, and is reset when the actual buffer is released. This could be later, because there is another observable which ticks when there is no request currently in progress. By [zipping](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) these two ticks together, `Buffer` can be used to emit a batch as soon as both criteria are met.

Usage is as follows:

```
source
  .BufferAndAct(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), 25, async batch =>
    await SendToDatabase(batch)
  )
  .Subscribe(r => {})
```

And the source for both extensions:

```
public static IObservable<TDest> BufferAndAct<TSource, TDest>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        TimeSpan timeSpan,
        int count,
        Func<IList<TSource>, Task<TDest>> action
)
{
    return new AnonymousObservable<TDest>(observer =>
    {
        var actionStartedObserver = new Subject<Unit>();
        var actionCompleteObserver = new Subject<Unit>();
        var published = source.Publish();
        var batchReady = published.Select(i => Unit.Default).Split(actionStartedObserver).Select(s => s.Buffer(timeSpan, count).Select(u => Unit.Default).Take(1)).Concat();
        var disposable = published.Buffer(Observable.Zip(actionCompleteObserver.StartWith(Unit.Default), batchReady)).SelectMany(async list =>
        {
            actionStartedObserver.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            try
            {
                return await action(list);
            }
            finally
            {
                actionCompleteObserver.OnNext(Unit.Default);
            }
        }).Finally(() => {}).Subscribe(observer);
        published.Connect();
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            disposable.Dispose();
            actionCompleteObserver.Dispose();
        });
    });
}

public static IObservable<Unit> BufferAndAct<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        TimeSpan timeSpan,
        int count,
        Func<IList<TSource>, Task> action
)
{
    return BufferAndAct(source, timeSpan, count, s =>
    {
        action(s);
        return Task.FromResult(Unit.Default);
    });
}

public static IObservable<IObservable<TSource>> Split<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        IObservable<Unit> boundaries
)
{
    return Observable.Create<IObservable<TSource>>(observer =>
    {
        var tuple = Split(observer);
        var d1 = boundaries.Subscribe(tuple.Item2);
        var d2 = source.Subscribe(tuple.Item1);
        return Disposable.Create(() =>
        {
            d2.Dispose();
            d1.Dispose();
        });
    });
}

private static Tuple<IObserver<TSource>, IObserver<Unit>> Split<TSource>(this IObserver<IObservable<TSource>> output)
{
    ReplaySubject<TSource> obs = null;
    var completed = 0; // int not bool to use in interlocked
    Action newObservable = () =>
    {
        obs?.OnCompleted();
        obs = new ReplaySubject<TSource>();
        output.OnNext(obs);
    };
    Action completeOutput = () =>
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref completed, 0, 1) == 1)
        {
            output.OnCompleted();
        }
    };
    newObservable();
    return new Tuple<IObserver<TSource>, IObserver<Unit>>(Observer.Create<TSource>(obs.OnNext, output.OnError, () =>
    {
        obs.OnCompleted();
        completeOutput();
    }), Observer.Create<Unit>(s => newObservable(), output.OnError, () => completeOutput()));
}
```

Comment: this is a cool extension, though I had the impression that Subscribe is not called in parallel. So if you not await you should be able to preserve the order.

Comment: Fair point. The pipeline I’m working on is all parallel and async, and we wouldn’t want anything to block. I guess if you were just running on one thread, and didn’t mind it blocking, then not calling await would stop anything coming through from source until it was done.

Comment: Turns out split is in fact just Window, which already exists. I'll edit this at some point.